# In Xcode 4.1 Database file is not displaying in build file

Tags: iphone

Using xcode 4.1 I am developing an application which is having database integration. I am able to do all functions on firefox Sqlite Manager plugin. When I add data to firefox, the data is being added properly by query. But I am not able to find the database file in the build folder of my application.
How can I get this file from within the application and from where ?
I have to check that the data inserted from the application is properly inserted or not because at the time of selecting & displaying the data, the application crashes.

Thanks in advance for guiding me & solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run application in iphone simolator and then insert data and the see the sqlite file at the path

```
home>Library>Application Support>Iphone Simulator>simulator type(like 5.0)>Applications
```

this path have many folders. folders have application data of all installed applications in simulator. search for your application and the open

```
Documents folder
```

here you have your sqlite file which store all your inserted data

Sometimes folders are hidden. so please check for hidden files and folders

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks @Mahendra...How can i check for the hidden files & floders...? Iphone Simulator folder is not shown in my system.

Comment: In which library folder you entered. you have to click on the left side bar icon which have home image and your system name and then go to library.

if you are there then retry for the hidden files and folders. thats all

Comment: All the steps suggested by you, i have tried but this thing is not navigating me to the Iphone Simulator.

Comment: ok dear. you are not getting this all but it is the only way to get the database file.